# Property of probability

Tags: probability

I want to ask a simple question regarding probability theory.

$A$ is a number of vehicles in a system, which is a discrete random variable that follows poisson distribution. And $\alpha$ is a specified probability which is a probability that the number of vehicle will exceed 15.

if $P(A>15)<\alpha$,

then $P(A \le 15) \ge 1-\alpha$

Is this correct according to properties of probability?

Comment: Yes. We have $P(A \leq 15) = 1 - P[(a \leq 15)^c] = 1 - P(A > 15) > 1 - \alpha \geq 1 - \alpha$, where $(A \leq 15)^c$ is the complement of $A \leq 15$

Comment: @perpetuallyconfused Many thanks. I get that $1-P(A>15)>1-\alpha$, but why it is also $>=1-\alpha$?

Comment: In general we have $P(E)+P(E^c) = 1$, so if $P(E)<\alpha$ we must have $P(E^c) = 1-P(E) > 1-\alpha$. So the above is true, but could be made slightly stricter ($>)$ instead of $\ge$). The result has nothing to do with the underlying distribution.

Comment: As @copper.hat says, we're just weakening our conclusion. If we know that something is _strictly_ greater, then certainly it is greater than or equal.